# Certbot Unable to find a Route53 hosted zone for _acme-challenge.subdomain.domain.com

Tags: linux, ssl, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt, certbot

I would like to create an SSL certificate using certbot for subdomains pointing to my domain. But upon generating the command below, I am receiving this error: `certbot.errors.PluginError: Unable to find a Route53 hosted zone for _acme-challenge.hello.example.com`

Here's the command:

```
sudo certbot certonly -d hello.example.com --dns-route53 -n --agree-tos --non-interactive --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -i apache
```

Main subdomain: `my.subdomain.com`

Other subdomains:

1. hello.example.com -> CNAME to secure.subdomain.com
2. world.another-example.com -> CNAME to secure.subdomain.com

So visiting these subdomains should show the my.subdomain.com webpage with their corresponding SSL certificate.

Answer (score 4):

This error usually occurs when you have valid AWS credentials, but your domain is not listed in Route53 of that AWS account.

Comment: So how to fix it?

Comment: @Huan just transfer your domain to your proper aws account

Comment: If I do not transfer domain to AWS, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

1. Check ~/.aws/credentials file - does it contain credentials for particular aws account with this hosted-zone
2. It should be default profile. e.x.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = your_aws_id_hosted_zone
aws_secret_access_key = your_aws_secret_hosted_zone
```